# REACT Failed to compile. ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/www/myfirstreact/node_modules/.ca che

Tags: reactjs

I just created my first REACT project and when I do "npm start" I get

```
Failed to compile.

ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
'/var/www/myfirstreact/node_modules/.cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)?

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Using this will setup the file structure for you, amongst other things.